# Excel 2007: How to display mm:ss format not as a DateTime (e.g. 73:07)?

Tags: ms-office, excel-2007

I need to create and Excel table that computes daily training times. each row has the following fields: Date, Distance, Time and Minutes/Km.
 My main problem is that I want to display the Time in format of `mm:ss`. For example: 24 min and 3 sec should be `24:03`, but "Excel" turns it to 00:03:00 (3 min after midnight). I've tried setting up "special formatting" but still "Excel insists" on formatting the hours. More over, training may exceed 60 minutes and I still want it only as `mm:ss`
My second question is after I'm done with the formatting issue, what is the simple way to compute Time/Distance?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

enter the values as `0:mm:ss` and format as `[m]:ss`

as this is now in the mins & seconds, simple arithmetic will allow you to calculate your statistics

Comment: OK. One problem is what if I exceed 59 minuts of training. Can I enter 0:62:30?

Comment: yes. I tried it by entering `0:74:03`, and it displayed it as expected - `74:03`

Answer (score 2):

Excel shows 24:03 as 3 minutes when you format it as time, because 24:03 is the same as 12:03 AM (in military time).

### Use General Format to Add Times

Instead of trying to format as Time, use the **General Format** and the following formula:

`=number of minutes + (number of seconds / 60)`

Ex: for 24 minutes and 3 seconds:

`=24+3/60`

This will give you a value of 24.05.

Do this for each time period. Let's say you enter this formula in cells `A1` and `A2`. Then, to get the total sum of elapsed time, use this formula in cell `A3`:

`=INT(A1+A2)+MOD(A1+A2,1)`

### Convert back to minutes and seconds

If you put `=24+3/60` into each cell, you will have a value of **48.1** in cell `A3`.

Now you need to convert this back to minutes and seconds. Use the following formula in cell `A4`:

`=MOD(A3,1)*60`

This takes the decimal portion and multiples it by 60. Remember, we divided by 60 in the beginning, so to convert it back to seconds we need to multiply.

You could have also done this separately, i.e. in cell A3 use this formula:

`=INT(A1+A2)`

and this formula in cell `A4`:

`=MOD(A1+A2,1)*60`

Here's a screenshot showing the final formulas:

[image: adding times]

Comment: OK, so basically my "TIME" column should be formatted as text -> receiving "24:03", then I need a 2nd column that extracts the minutes and seconds (using LEFT & RIGHT) and with the input performing the: (24+3/60) then I can compute the Time/Distance. And now reformat the result using the MOD. correct?

Comment: No. The time column must be `mm+s/60` where `mm` is the number of minutes and `s` is the number of seconds. If you enter `24:03` and use `Left` on it, you get `1`, not `24`.

Comment: fine, but I dont want to complecate the input entering (after every training). I want that each time any user will just enter his training time (and distance) and get his training rate (time/distance)

Answer (score 2):

To make life easier when entering multiple dates/times it is possible to use a custom format to remove the need to enter the colon, and the leading "hour" 0.  This however requires a second field for the numerical date to be stored, as the displayed date from the custom format is in base 10.

***Displaying* a number as a time** (no need to enter colons, but no time conversion)

For displaying the times on the sheet, and for entering them without having to type the colon set the cell format to custom and use:

`0/:00`

Then enter your time.  For example, if you wanted to enter 62:30, then you would simply type 6230 and your custom format would visually insert a colon 2 decimal points from the right.

If you only need to display the times, stop here.

**Converting number to time**

If you need to be able to calculate with the times, you will need to convert them from base 10 into the time format.

This can be done with the following formula (change `A2` to the relevant cell reference):

`=TIME(0,TRUNC(A2/100),MOD(A2,100))`

- `=TIME` starts the number to time conversion
- We don't need hours, so enter `0,` at the beginning of the formula, as the format is always `hh,mm,ss` (to display hours and minutes instead of minutes and seconds, place the 0 at the end of the formula).
- For the minutes, `TRUNC(A2/100),` discards the rightmost 2 digits.
- For the seconds, `MOD(A2,100)` keeps the rightmost 2 digits and discards everything to the left.

The above formula was found and adapted from this article:
[PC Mag.com - Easy Date and Time Entry in Excel](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2316755,00.asp)

Alternatively, you could skip the `0/:00` custom formatting, and just enter your time in a cell to be referenced of the edge of the visible workspace or on another sheet as you would for the custom formatting (ie: 6230 for 62:30)

Then change the display format of the cells with the formula to `[m]:ss` as @Sean Chessire suggested.

Here is a screen shot to show what I mean.

[image: Excel screen shot showing time conversion formula and custom formatting]

Comment: I'm using Office 2010 and for the Format needed to use 0\:00, not 0/:00, then this works great.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hand inputted data, you can enter your data as `mm:ss,0` or `mm:ss.0` depending on your language/region selection instead of `00:mm:ss`.

You need to specify your cell format as `[m]:ss` if you like to see all minutes seconds format instead of hours minutes seconds format.

Answer (score 0):

as text:

```
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(cell;"d");" days ";TEXT(cell;"t");" hours ";MID(TEXT(cell;"hh:mm:ss");4;2);" minutes ";TEXT(cell;"s");" seconds")
```

Answer (score 0):

5.In the Format Cells box, click Custom in the Category list. 
6.In the Type box, at the top of the list of formats, type [h]:mm;@ and then click OK. (That’s a colon after [h], and a semicolon after mm.)
YOu can then add hours. The format will be in the Type list the next time you need it.

From MS, works well.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-or-subtract-time-HA102809662.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One convenient trick to entering elapsed times into Excel is to have two zeros and a colon before the number of minutes, details follow. For copy and paste operations into Excel without have to worry about formatting at all one can use the format 00:XX:XX where XX are two digits totaling < 60. In that case, Excel will echo 0:XX:XX in the cell contents displayed and store the data as 12:XX:XX AM. If one pastes data in a 00:XXX:XX format into Excel, or 00:XX:XX where either XX > 59 this will be converted into a fraction of a day.

For example, 00:121:12 becomes 0.0841666666666667, which if multiplied by the number of seconds in a day, 86,400, becomes 7272 s. Next, 00:21:12 would by default show 0:21:12 stored as 12:21:12 AM. Finally, 00:21:60 becomes 0.0152777777777778, also a fraction of a day.

This suggestion is made merely to avoid having to worry about specific formatting in Excel, and letting the program worry about it. Note, for Excel data internally formatted as 12:XX:XX AM one can only use certain Excel commands, for example, one can take an average. However, subtraction will only work when the result is a positive number. Such that converting times into seconds, fractions of a day, or other real number is suggested for access to more complete arithmetic operation coverage.

For example, if one has a column of mixed time formats, or times that are negative and will not display, if one changes the number formatting to General, all the times will be converted to fractions of a day.