# Excel - Format cell as duration (mm:ss)

Tags: excel, format, duration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel 2007: How to display mm:ss format not as a DateTime (e.g. 73:07)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095994/excel-2007-how-to-display-mmss-format-not-as-a-datetime-e-g-7307)

I am trying to put in some jogging sessions in excel, and are really surprised how difficult it is to format cells as I want to.

The task is simple, I want to show data as mm:ss, and if the sessions have been longer than that, hh:mm:ss. Is that possible? I thought it was going to work with [h]:mm:ss, but it just keeps formatting the cells to something like 1900-01-xx yy:zz...

So the hard thing may be that I want to write minutes as default. Like 27:59, or 72:59. (in the second case an automatic conversion to 01:12:59 would be a good thing)

Comment: ??? WHen I enter a time like 3:20, Excel understands  it perfectly and formats it accordingly by itself. So what do you really enter ? Try clearing the format of the problematic cell to see what value it contains. 1 hour is the 24th part of a day, so its value should be around 1/24 = 0,041666667

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate. That's exactly what I want to achieve. Should I remove my question in some way?

Comment: But the answers does not work for me. To format the cell as [m]:ss.
If I insert 28:59, the result is 1739:00
Edit: Ok, it actually works, if you type 0:28:59, but I don't want to have to write the zero. ;)